# CharacterInString not producing expected result

Tags: objective-c, nscharacterset

I have this code:

```
NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"];

NSLog(@"character set: %i", [characterSet characterIsMember:(unichar)"a"]);
```

The NSLog returns 0, when I expect it to return 1. How am i doing this wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have cast a *C string* (a *pointer* to `char`) to `unichar`.
Replacing `"a"` by `'a'` produces the expected result:

```
NSLog(@"character set: %i", [characterSet characterIsMember:(unichar)'a']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Martin is fully true; what can be a real-life situation when you read your unichar from string :

```
NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"];
unichar character = [@"cba" characterAtIndex:2];
NSLog(@"character set: %d", [characterSet characterIsMember:character]);
```

In that case casting is not an issue, *characterAtIndex* returns the properly typed char.